# Opening dialog box through a service

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

Here is the problem:

I have a `nav` bar having some `nav options` including *login* button which is situated in `app.component.html`

This is structure of `AppComponent`:

```
export class AppComponent {

logInDialogRef: MdDialogRef<LoginComponent>;

public constructor(public http: Http, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, 
          public dialog: MdDialog) {}

loginUser(){
    let config = new MdDialogConfig();
    config.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;
    config.role = 'dialog';
    config.width = '40%';
    this.logInDialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, config);
}
}
```

When I click on *login*, I get nice pop up for login. I have another *nav option* which is protected route.

```
{path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

Suppose I am on some route say `solutions`. From here I login, I store `jwt token` in `localstorage`. Then I click on `Products`. Since user is logged in it should navigate or it should give pop up if no user is logged in.

But I'm getting nothing. Getting following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
```

`CanActivate` method of Auth.Guard.ts

```
canActivate() {
if (tokenNotExpired()) {
    return true;
}

this.loginService
    .loginUser(this.viewContainerRef)
    .subscribe(res => this.result = res);

return false;
}
```

`LoginService` have same `loginUser` method as above in `app.component`

`app/login/login.service.ts`

```
public loginUser(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef): Observable<any> {

    let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<LoginComponent>;
    let config = new MdDialogConfig();
    config.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    config.role = 'dialog';
    config.width = '40%';
    dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, config);
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
}
```

I hope information is clear. Please tell if further clarification is needed.

The problem is opening `dialog` from different component through a service while same can be done from individual component easily i.e. `app.component` in this case.

Comment: Can you show us full code of `AuthGuard`?

Comment: This is more or less there is in `AuthGuard`. I'm using `angular2-jwt` library for authentication And it is working fine when using without `dialogbox` i.e. there is separate route for login

Comment: Do you have `private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef` in constructor of AuthGuard? That's problem. This service doesn't see your injecting

Comment: Made is public but didn't work

Comment: It doesn't matter. Angular can't find provider for it

Comment: How can we provide `ViewContainerRef` to service?

Comment: One minute please

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

**Auth.Guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = appRef.components[0].instance.viewContainerRef;
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Check also my **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GOeiIa8S25wrZGURjl2o?p=preview)** (There is used lazy loading for `ProductsModule`)

Comment: Error about `ViewContainerRef` went away. But now it can't find `MdDialogRef`. Another error showed up `Error: No provider for MdDialogRef`